# Why can't a static member variable be defined inside main()?

Tags: c++, static

```
class test 
{
public:
  static int i;

  int func() {
    return i;
  }
};

int main() 
{ 
  test::i = 20;
}
```

fails to compile with `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

If I make the static variable `inline`, I can define it inside `main`. Or if I don't make it inline, I can define it between the class declaration and `main()` like so:

```
class test 
{
public:
  static int i;

  int func() {
    return i;
  }
};

int test::i = 20;

int main() 
{ 

}
```

Why does this work but the former doesn't? 
Also, why is an `int` here needed when it's already been declared as an `int` inside `test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a function, the statement

```
test::i = 20;
```

is an expression (not a definition). It stores the value 20 into `test::i`. But if `test::i` was never defined, you cannot store a value into it.

On the other hand, at namespace scope, when you write

```
int test::i = 20;
```

this is a definition of `test::i`.

Comment: I think I'm confused by the terminology "definition" when it's applied to variables. Inside `test` class, when I wrote `static int i`, is this only a declaration and not a definition?

Comment: @David correct.  For a non-const `static` class variable, you *declare* it in the class, and you also have to *define* the actual memory storage for the variable, too. That *definition* is done outside of the class. Then, inside of functions, you can *assign* values to that storage

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh I see. If I had some local variable within a function, then the moment it's declared is also the moment it's defined right? The distinction with the current situation is that the variable is static?

Comment: @David Yes, local variables are declared and defined at the same time. Even for `static` local variables.  It is `static` *class* variables that are treated a little differently.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah I see. Now that I think about it, normal non-static class member variables aren't declared and defined at the same time either, right? Definition seems to be when the variable occupies memory, which doesn't happen until an instance of the class is instantiated.

Comment: @David A declaration *declares* that a particular name denotes a variable or function of a given type. A definition *creates* a variable or function with a particular name. As Remy Lebeau explains, some static class member declarations are not definitions.

Comment: Right, I understand now. It's the same as functions -- I just haven't really seen it used for variables. Also, why are you not allowed to define `test::i` inside `main()` or any function for that matter?

Comment: @David I don't know the reason why that restriction exists.